# How to make overlay effect responsive with image

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

[image: Responsive Image]

[image]

Hello !
I made the above image responsive for 320x767 pixel screen resolution. My code is working properly.

However, I have a problem, the shadow effect created on image is not behaving responsively. What i want is as my image become smaller, the shadow should also become smaller with the image height. Or it should behave responsive
What should i do for that?

html

```
<body>
<div  class=" background-img">
    <img src="img/learning.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="overlay">
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Css

```
.background-img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px){

  .background-img{
        width: 426px !important;
        height: 320px !important ;
    }
    .overlay{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30% !important;
    height: 25%!important;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: remove `position:fixed` an absolute will do and set your width and height to 100% also add `position:relative` to background-img

Comment: try using position as relative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image overlay on responsive sized images bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263800/image-overlay-on-responsive-sized-images-bootstrap)

Comment: @winresh24
Which width and height should be 100%?
And in media query background-image needs to be set at position relative?

Comment: wait I will make a fiddle for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually apply a z-index declaration to the popout div using a slightly higher value (10 as you are using), along with a position: relative; declaration that causes the z-index value to be applied. 
Here's the code change if you're following the way I understood:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px){

 .background-img{
    position:relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
 }
 .overlay {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100% !important;
   height: 100% !important;
   z-index: 10;
   background-color:black;
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I don't want width and height of overlay class 100%, rather than i want to it to be width:55% and height 50%. So in your solution; it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code you didn't need query to make it responsive:
https://jsfiddle.net/52ms14gf/1/

```
.background-img .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.background-img .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
.container{position:relative;
  }

.container img{width:100%;
 display:block;
 }
```

Comment: Hey!
There is only one problem with your solution. The overlay going beyond the boundary of image. How should i control that ?

Comment: take a look at the image it was not crop properly try to change it

Comment: where? paste the link

Comment: See the image attached with my question above

Comment: okay check it again I update the image in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/52ms14gf/2/

Comment: What piece of code you updated?
The code is duplicate with the previous one.

Comment: Put width:50% and height:50% and then see the effect. Why it's going out of the boundry of image ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111606/discussion-between-winresh24-and-bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide).

Answer (score 1):

Try with this CSS:

```
.background-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px) {
    .background-img{
        width: 426px !important;
        height: 320px !important ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `%` in height and width of overlay.

Give a fixed height and width in `px`

```
.overlay{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px !important; // set accordinly
    height: 100px !important;// set accordinly
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

> width and height declared in `%` will work according to the height and width of parent. If you don't want the child to change its height and width just define it in `px` for all screens.

Answer (score 0):

I used CSS-grid like so:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.img-responsive {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and that worked well on all screen widths.